# Basic Cursor in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am looking for basic direction on Cursor use in MSSS.

Say there is a table, `TABLE1`, with 2 fields (`ID`, `Date`).  The `ID` is *not* a unique key.  The table records events by id, and some ids occur frequently, some infrequently.

For example:

```
ID  |  Date
1   |  2010-01-01
2   |  2010-02-01
3   |  2010-02-15
2   |  2010-02-15
4   |  2010-03-01
```

I would like to create a new table with the following fields: ID, Date, Number of times ID appears in 6 months previous to Date, Number of times ID appears in 6 months after Date.

Is there a best way to go about accomplishing this?  Thanks kindly.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it needs a cursor. A basic `SELECT` with `COUNT()`, `CASE` and `GROUP BY` should produce the entire result, as a set.

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this, and from which date you want the calculation 6 months before or after.

Comment: Don't waste your time learning about cursors - learn about **how to AVOID** cursors!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you clarify how to use Case in this instance?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one side (I think - not tested)

```
select t1.id, t1.date, count(*) as 'count'
from table t1 
join table t2 
  on t2.id = t1.id
 and DateDiff(mm,t1.date,t2.date) <= 6 
 and DateDiff(mm,t1.date,t2.date) >  0 
group by t1.id, t1.date
```

I think you can skip the > 0 and use case to count the positive and negative

```
sum(WHEN t1.date > t2.date then 0 else 1) as prior 
sum(WHEN t1.date < t2.date then 0 else 1) as next 

and DateDiff(mm,t1.date,t2.date) <= 6 
and DateDiff(mm,t2.date,t2.date) <= 6
```

May have prior and next backwards

Comment: there is currently only 1 table, what t2 do you have in mind?

Comment: T2 is an alias. You have never seen a self join?  Did you try this?

Comment: I am trying this now---it doesn't seem to like the datediff formatting.  Thanks for your help. Also, I have also moved this question to new question to avoid the Cursor misnomer.

Comment: There was a comma that should have been a period.   And you should NOT re-post the same question.  Edit the existing question.