# Query Construction: Count, Case, Datediff, and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

[Reframing prior question, which had been posed as a question about Cursors.]

I am looking for a way to select counts under certain date conditions.

Say there is a table, `T1`, with 2 fields (`ID`, `Date`). The `ID` is not a unique key. The table records events by id, and some ids occur frequently, some infrequently.

For example:

```
ID  |  Date
1   |  2010-01-01
2   |  2010-02-01
3   |  2010-02-15
2   |  2010-02-15
4   |  2010-03-01
```

I would like to create a new table with the following fields: ID, Date, Count of times ID appears in 6 months previous to Date, Count of times ID appears in 6 months after Date.

In essence, for every row in the existing table, I want to add a column that looks back for times the same ID has appeared in previous six months, and look ahead for times the same ID has appeared in following six months.

So the output for the example would hopefully look something like:

```
ID  |  Date        | Lookback  |  Lookahead
1   |  2010-01-01  | 0         |  0
2   |  2010-02-01  | 0         |  1
3   |  2010-02-15  | 0         |  0
2   |  2010-02-15  | 1         |  0
4   |  2010-03-01  | 0         |  0
```

Is there a best way to formulate the appropriate query?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include expected output based on the sample data you posted?

Comment: What query?  You didn't describe a query, you described a *table*?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Cursor in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701044/basic-cursor-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a self join (Assuming you have a primary key of KeyID):

```
SELECT  T.ID,
        T.Date,
        Lookback = COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Date < T.Date THEN t2.ID END),
        Lookahead = COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Date > T.Date THEN t2.ID END)
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN T t2
            ON t2.ID = t.ID
            AND t2.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, T.Date)
            AND T2.Date < DATEADD(MONTH, 6, T.Date)
GROUP BY T.ID, T.Date, T.KeyID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0c13/1)**

The key is that it just joins all rows for the previous 6 months and the next 6 months, and counts the result. The `COUNT(CASE WHEN...` ensures that for the `before` column you are only counting the records before, and the after only the records after.

Comment: Hi, thank you, can you explain why the number of rows in the join is smaller than in the original table? Is it because the table is not unique on ID and Date?

Comment: It shouldn't be, in the example I have posted it is the same number (5).

Comment: I'm not sure it's working.  It comes down from 18,000 rows to 11,000.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, it is because (`ID`, `Date`) are not unique to each other. Do yo have a Primary key on the table? If so, add this to the `GROUP BY` and you should resolve the issue of removing rows.

Comment: I can make one.  If the primary Key were Key_ID, how would I change the query?